# Minecraft Command - Execute commands relative to the block broken by the player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The idea is this, when the player breaks a block with a tag *(to distinguish same type of block without the tag)*, it executes commands relative to the position of the block broken by the player. For example, summon a gold ingot relative to the block when the player breaks it. The purpose of making it relative the block instead of the player is that I want something to happen above/under/etc. the block.

The closest thing I can find is [this](https://www.planetminecraft.com/project/execute-commands-relative-to-blocks/). It replaces the blocks player putting down with another block.

Comment: well then use that trick to implement what you want it to do...

Comment: You better write a mod for this and use Forge event handler.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík He shouldn't need a mod for this.

Answer (score -1):

there is a relatively easy way to do this:
basically what you want to do is set up a stat.mineBlock.{block} objective for the block you want to track, then execute at every player that has a score of 1 for that objective.
Find the item that normally drops from that block in a radius around the player with an Age of 0 (or 1, not sure which one it gets initialised with) and execute off of that whatever you want to do.

Here is an example code, using a `gold_block` as the block to break and `goldBlock` as the objective (untested and maybe buggy, but should give you an idea of how it works):

```
[tag new item] /execute @a[score_goldBlock_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players tag @e[type=item,r=10] add executeHere {Item:{id:gold_block,Count:1b},Age:0}
[insert what you want to do here, e.g.] /execute @e[type=item,tag=executeHere] ~ ~ ~ /summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:gold_ingot,Count:1b}}
[remove tag] /scoreboard players tag @e[type=item,tag=executeHere] remove executeHere
[reset score] /scoreboard players set @a[score_goldBlock_min=1] goldBlock 0
```

Comment: This is relative to the player, not the block

Comment: It is not. Read the second command again. @pppery

Comment: Oh, I see. I misread the code.